# Sink Function in R

Tags: r, date, auto-update, requirements.txt, sink

I am trying to update the name of a sink file automatically with a date but am not having any luck.  The below is what I have, any suggestions?

```
time.stamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%m/%d/%Y")
nameFile <- paste(time.stamp, ".txt", sep = "")
sink(nameFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

the slash '/' character is invalid for naming files.  Try with some other character

```
time.stamp <- format(Sys.time(), "%m.%d.%Y")
```

for example will allow your code to execute.